# how to create pl sql function to Checking if data exists in database or not

Tags: sql, database, function, plsql, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a function that tells whether data exist in database or not. Trying to solve this using cursor if data exist then data will be fetched from database and value of temp will be `TRUE` otherwise data would not be fetched from DB and it will set value of temp to `false`.

But when I compile this function it gives warning that

> **Warning: Function created with compilation errors.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_DATA(Eid IN varchar2(5))
RETURN boolean 
IS 
    cursor cemp is select EMPNO from employee where EMPNO = Eid ;
    eno employee.EMPNO%TYPE ;
    temp number;
BEGIN 
    open cemp ;
    fetch cemp into eno ;
    if(cemp%notfound)then
        temp := FALSE ;
    else 
        temp := TRUE ;
    End if ;
    close cemp ;
    return temp ;
END; 
/
```

Comment: That's an elaborate way to return `cemp%found`.

Comment: Are you asking how to display PL/SQL compilation errors in general? That will depend on your development tools.

Comment: Your return value, `temp` needs to be `boolean` but is defined as a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommended to use an [implicit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm) cursor and don't bother for open/closed;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_DATA(Eid IN varchar2(5)) RETURN boolean IS 
  n number;
BEGIN 
 select count(*) into n
 from employee where EMPNO = Eid ;
 if (n > 0) then
   return true;  
 else
    return false;
 end if;
END; 
/
```

Comment: This is good, but can be shortened. It is not necessary to test the count itself and take action on it. The condition (n>0) produces a boolean result and can be returned directly.  So instead of "if ... end if;"  just use "return n>0;"

Answer (score 0):

you can use cursor like this  [Reference](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3817416?start=15&tstart=0)

```
 DECLARE

       CURSOR cCheck (p_Param IN NUMBER) IS

          SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ 99

          FROM   my_table

          WHERE  some_column = p_Param

          FOR UPDATE; 

       v_dummy       NUMBER;

       v_row_exists  BOOLEAN;



       v_test    NUMBER := 1;  -- This would actually come from a parameter or somewhere

    BEGIN



       OPEN cCheck(v_test);

       FETCH cCheck INTO v_dummy;

       v_row_exists := cCheck%FOUND;

       CLOSE cCheck;



       IF v_row_Exists THEN

          ... Do something that can't be done with MERGE

       END IF;

       CLOSE cCheck;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
function CHECK_DATA(Eid IN varchar2(5)) return boolean is PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
Begin
Declare
n integer;
begin
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from employee where EMPNO ='||Eid||'' into n;
   if n > 0 then
     return true;  
   else
     return false;
   end if;
end;
End;
/
```